# If I completely remake the home page of a studiopress child theme, what will the effects be if the genesis framework gets updated?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I am considering building 2 searchbars in the home page of a studiopress child theme. I have to figure out how to build the PHP "backend" processes for these searchbars. How to do this is not the question but what will it mean for updates by studiopress of the genesis framework. For example Will it still work after updates if I build it properly in the child theme?

I am still new to coding (done only some codecademy stuff) and am still figuring out what the best way is to build my website. Answer to this question will help me make choices. For example I could also make a custom theme with the genesis framework but currently I think that would be more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make changes to the theme, they will be overwritten when the theme updates. There are som options:

- You could create a custom plugin and then add the searchbars using a
  hook. (Your best choice)
- You could duplicate the theme and change the version to 99, so this
  theme doesn't get updated
- Create a local backup, and manually commit changes to template files when the theme has updated

Comment: Appreciate the answer alot. However I thought that if changes were made in a "child" theme the update of the "parent" theme would not affect the "child theme". Or are you saying that creating a searchbar is impossible without making changes to the parent theme? That custom plugin sounds like a good option thank you :)

Comment: When you update the parent theme, changes in your childtheme won't be affected. If you add the searchbar to header.php, and this file gets updated in your parent theme, you should manually overwrite your changed header.php